# serialization error when compiling with boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compilation

I'm trying to compile a piece of software called Bagel (a quantum chemistry program, some info are [here](https://nubakery.org/quickstart/installation_guide.html)) written in C++ and which uses Boost.

I get a compilation error, and as I don't know C++ and I've never used boost I'm essentially lost. The author of the program says the problem I'm experiences depends on my boost installation and not on the program itself.

I installed boost 1.73.0 (Linux Mint 20, g++  9.3.0) doing:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
sudo ./b2 install
```

When compiling the program I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:119:11: error: ‘class std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
  119 |         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
      |         ~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned
 int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:69:22:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) 
[with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:18:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:148:40:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, const void*) const [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:101:1:   required from ‘class boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, std::unordered_set<long unsigned int> >’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:253:13:   required from ‘static void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::save_standard::invoke(Archive&, const T&) [with T = std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>; Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:308:22:   [ skipping 21 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
...
```

The following post https://lists.boost.org/boost-users//2014/03/81583.php report on a similar error, but I don't understand what I should to solve it.
*Any* help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Requirements say

> Boost C++ Libraries - Version 1.53.0 or newer

Boost is famous of making non-backward compatible changes. 1.73 is quite distant from 1.53. I would try to install 1.53 which author of Bagel had to use and this one worked at least for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I got a similar error message when compiling Bagel using v1.53.0 of Boost (see below).  However, when using Boost v1.70.0 (following [this comment](https://github.com/qsimulate-open/bagel/issues/182#issuecomment-533608948)) I did not get the error anymore.

I was able to compile Bagel successfully on CentOS 7 using gcc 7.3.1 and Intel OneAPI 2021.3, as well as on Ubuntu 20.04 using gcc 9.4.0 and the same version of Intel OneAPI.

One additional note was that I built Boost from source because the library files provided by the package manager were not found by configure (it expects the headers to be in `$BOOST_ROOT/include` and libraries to be in `$BOOST_ROOT/lib`.

```
libtool: compile: mpicxx -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/smith -I../..
-I/opt/boost/include -I../../.. -DNDEBUG -O3 -mavx -MT tensor.lo -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/tensor.Tpo -c ../../../src/smith/tensor.cc -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/tensor.o

In file included from
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_member.hpp:23:0,

... (lots of lines)

/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:11: error: 'class
std::unordered_set<long unsigned int>' has no member named 'serialize'
t.serialize(ar, file_version); ~~^~~~~~~~~
```